# Service account with fine grained permissions for managing PostgreSQL databases

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I need to create a service account for managing (create, update, delete) PostgreSQl database instances in Cloud SQL. I was thinking to use "roles/cloudsql.editor" role, but it does not have permission for deleting databases.
Must I use the editor primitive role for deletion? If so, can I somehow limit it to have permissions to delete  Cloud SQL instances only?

As a second option, should I maybe create a custom role based on the "roles/cloudsql.editor" and extend it with some deletion permission for Cloud SQL instances?

Best Regards,

Jovan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) and apply the [IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) you require. Thereafter, you can [grant this custom role to your service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console). In your senario, I assume you need the following permissions:

```
cloudsql.databases.create
cloudsql.databases.delete
cloudsql.databases.update
```